# Exception not being thrown in setter

Tags: c#, xunit

I've created a class "BankAccount.cs" and am using xunit to test it. I'm testing whether the constructor throws an ArgumentException if it's provided with an empty string as an argument (the argument is the bank account number as a string).

My test fails because no Exception is being thrown - I can't figure out why not.

It appears that the constructor isn't even being called; if I let the constructor throw an Exception (rather than implementing this in the setter of AccountNumber), none is thrown either. Also, if I use Console.WriteLine to debug manually, nothing is written to the console.

Exceptions (Debugging) are set to default settings.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Banking.Models
{
    public class BankAccount : IBankAccount
    {
        /* NOTE: I've deleted non-relevant fields, properties and methods for brevity */

        private string _accountNumber;

        public string AccountNumber
        {
            get { return _accountNumber; }
            set
            {
                if(value == string.Empty)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Accountnumber must have a value");
                _accountNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public BankAccount(string account)
        {
            AccountNumber = account;
            Balance = Decimal.Zero;
            _transactions = new List<Transaction>();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{AccountNumber} - {Balance}";
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            BankAccount account = obj as BankAccount;
            if (account == null) return false;
            return AccountNumber == account.AccountNumber;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return AccountNumber?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
using System;
using Xunit;
using Banking.Models;

namespace Tests.Models
{
    public class BankAccountTest : IDisposable
    {
        // private variables
        private BankAccount _account;
        private string AccountNumber { get; set; }

        // Setup
        public BankAccountTest()
        {
            AccountNumber = "123-4567890-02";
            _account = new BankAccount(AccountNumber);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void NewAccount_BalanceZero()
        {
            Assert.Equal(0, _account.Balance);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void NewAccount_CorrectAccountNumber()
        {
            Assert.Equal(AccountNumber, _account.AccountNumber);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void NewAccount_EmptyString_Fails()
        {
            Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(
                () => new BankAccount(string.Empty));
        }

        // TearDown
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `==` you should be using `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))`

Comment: I cannot repro this, the exception is thrown: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UU3tHN

Comment: @RonBeyer That doesn't make a difference here

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It shouldn't, which is why I didn't post it as an answer, however it is the proper way of checking.

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm copying the instructor's solution. I had to manually add the references to xunit.core.dll and xunit.assert.dll to the solution, or it wouldn't run.

Comment: @TheFox Try stepping through the setter with the debugger, set a breakpoint in the setter and step through. You can see what the value of `value` is and where it comes from. If you are running it as a test project, the test should pass which means the exception *was* thrown.

Comment: null == String.IsEmpty will never return true. As Ron Beyer said, you really should be using String.IsNullOrEmpty or even .IsNullOrWhiteSpace for such checks. Considering this value is supposed to be a Number, you could even be doing a Parse rather then a Null/Empty check or both in sequence. You also may want to consider what I call "Passive error reporting" via INotifyDataErrorInfo (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx) or it's advanced borther whose name keeps escaping me.

Comment: @RonBeyer I was not aware of that functionality. I've tried implementing it, but nothing new happens while testing/debugging. I do have build errors which I've had for as long as I've been testing: CS0579 Duplicate 'System.Reflection.Assemblyxxxx' attribute. Other tests are behaving as expected.

Comment: @Christopher thanks for your comment, that's good to know. In any case, it does nothing to help me as it appears the code isn't even being executed in the first place.

Comment: @TheFox: If code is (seemingly) not executed, my first culptript is always the JiT and it's dead code detection. It should be turned off for debug builds, but I had issues with that before.

Comment: um *"I do have build errors which I've had for as long as I've been testing"* fix that first